# How can I use a different template file for the blog index's paginated pages?

Tags: theme-development

I tried different tests to make the home (a blog index, 3 latest posts) page use a different template than it's following generated paginated pages (blog.com/page/2). Essentially what I am trying to do is get my home page looking different with latest posts and the "Next Posts" links to the /page/2 with a different template. I thought this was common but can't seem to get it working.

**Test 1:**

In Settings->Reading->Homepage Display I set to "Your latest posts". Created a 'home.php' file with `has_posts()` loop and pagination. `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` returns **true** on both the home page and its following paginated pages.

**Test 2:**

In Settings->Reading->Homepage Display, I set to "Static Page" and set it to a Page I created in the Pages section. Created a page-home.php template file it reads from. `is_home()` returns **false** and `is_front_page()` returns **true** on both the home page and its following paginated pages.

**Test 3:**

The obvious `page.php` template file didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

`$paged` will have the value 1 in you are or the first page or the value of respective pagination page number.

Depending on this you can call `get_template_part()` to load the desired template for the page.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I see where you're going with this but when testing this, and my lack of knowledge of Wordpress, it came out loading the template file along with the home/index page. I ended up putting your code into the home page and just hiding the masthead when it's paged so I'll go ahead and mark this correct.

Comment: glad it helped...

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png

should use archive template for this.

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't mention but I did try to use that. Archive is different from pagination pages.